# (I think) Pirate related puzzle / riddle

Tags: riddle

"My first part rhymes a body part,

But it is not so close to your heart!

Reach the Shore and put feet on me,

My other part, on which you grow a tree!"

Any ideas?

Thanks guys

Comment: Are there two parts? I ask because the punctuation/capitalisation makes it ambiguous.

Comment: copied and pasted as it is, it's actually on separate lines however this website put it all into one line.

Comment: Punctuation and capitalisation should be ignored. I believe it's just two separate parts. I've been thinking maybe it's two words? or one single long word with two separate sections? I've been thinking... Hand -> Sand "Reach the shore and put feet on me", however I cannot think of what the second part could be. In the end it may not even be sand...

Comment: OK, so, you're saying that you don't know the answer to the puzzle that you posted?

Comment: It looks like you found it elsewhere so you should have added a link to the source.

Comment: It's ok to post something you don't know the answer to. Now you're just making the moderators' work harder. Just change the question back and accept the rhsquared's answer (tick on the left). No need to panic!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is NOT a puzzle.

Comment: @ABcDexter it was, the OP just edited over it. I just rolled it back to the puzzle.

Answer (score 3):

I admit that I took the answer from [the facebook](https://www.facebook.com/appbottled/photos/a.1130690040418663/1344807939006871/?type=3&theater)

> It's Thailand = Thigh + Land
>  "My first part rhymes a body part,
>  But it is not so close to your heart!
>  'Thai' = Thigh, it's not close to the heart and it rhymes with Thai
>  "Reach the Shore and put feet on me,
>  My other part, on which you grow a tree!"
>  This part gives us 'land'